# MYSQL two tables joining and getting result based on ONLY and ONLY by same field value

Tags: mysql, join

Details:

[image: http://screencast.com/t/fTRzyqso]

Basically there are 2 MYSQL tables (contacts and transactions) and need to get contactid on the basis of two conditions

1. Get all the contacts (contactid) where there is no transaction at all
2. Get only those contacts who has one or more transactions but all of them are with Cancel status.

Help!?

Comment: Are you asking for SQL code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually accomplish this with a simple LEFT join... and look for NULL (not found).  By doing a left-join, it gets all records from the left table regardless of a match on the right.  So, if we set the join condition to your transactions table SPECIFICALLY for Cancelled = "No", and we FIND a match, ignore that from the result set.  If there are no records in transactions, OR all of them are set to Cancelled = "Yes", they are excluded from the join condition and will thus be considered "none found"

```
select
      c.ContactID
   from
      Contacts c
         LEFT JOIN Transactions t
            on c.ContactID = t.ContactID
           AND t.Cancelled = "yes"
   where
      t.contactID is null
```

Comment: Ok this works, except I have to change t.Cancelled <> 'Yes' to get the correct result. Many thanks!

Comment: @Ahmed, ACTUALLY NO... you WANT TO LOOK for ANYTHING that has a YES...  If it FINDs one, those are the ones you want to ignore... hence the logical NEGATIVE would be NOT finding one and getting the NULL which I started with.  If your Cancelled status is all upper case, change to that "YES" or "Yes", whatever your consistent value setting would be.  But changing to <> "Yes" is getting NO answers.  What if someone has YES AND NO... It will find the NO, include it and falsely so since there was a YES left out of the test.

Comment: Executing ...
**select
      c.ContactID
   from
      Contacts c
         LEFT JOIN Transactions t
            on c.ContactID = t.ContactID
           AND t.Cancelled = "yes"
   where
      t.contactID is null**

I got 3,5,6

But executing 

**select
      c.ContactID
   from
      Contacts c
         LEFT JOIN Transactions t
            on c.ContactID = t.ContactID
           AND t.Cancelled = "no"
   where
      t.contactID is null**

gave me desired result of Contact Id 2,4,6
Make sense?

Comment: @Ahmed, no it doesn't, but as long as you are good with it, I would VERIFY those instances that HAD both YES and NO cancelled status entries.

Comment: your answer is very informative for me. Thanks again
This is what i meant to say just for the sake of understanding http://screencast.com/t/WuZlBPz6U31S